# Convert xml data into csv format

Tags: xml, csv, marklogic

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We have data in xml like this

```
<article type="current">
    <element1>
      <e1>9297862</e1>
      <e2>
        <yr>2007</yr>
      </e2>
       ....
       ....
    <element1>
    <indexing>
        <grp1>
          ..........
        <grp1>
        <grp2>
          .........
        </grp2>
    </indexing>
</article>
```

Like this we have long list.

We want to export these data in csv format. All array data should come in single column with comma separate values

We checked and there are 2 options TDE or using xslt.

We tried with xslt but it is getting too complicated as there are dynamic data and not available between documents.

What is best approach here? is there any example available for the same?

Comment: Not sure exactly why XSLT is too complicated. There are ways to ensure that you have consistent number of columns even if the data is sparse, but you haven't shown your code to see what you have been trying. Is this transforming a single document or a sequence of documents?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a minimal (but complete) example of the XML inputs and desired CSV output